# How to represent negative numbers in plural resources in android

Tags: android, xml, plural

I was wondering if there is any easy way to format an integer based on
negative, zero and positive using the plural resources mechanism in android?

My desired answer would be

- if getRemaining() < -1 then "|getRemaining()| days ago"
- if getRemaining() == -1 then "|getRemaining()| day ago"
- if getRemaining() == 0 then "getRemaining() days remaining"
- if getRemaining() == 1 then "getRemaining() day remaining"
- if getRemaining() > 1 then "getRemaining() days remaining"

Right now I achieve this by following code

```
if (item.getRemaining() > -1) {
        holder.remainingTV.setText(res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.plural_remaining, item.getRemaining(),
            item.getRemaining()));
} else {
        holder.remainingTV.setText(res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.plural_ago, -item.getRemaining(), -item.getRemaining()));
}
```

My resources looks like this

```
<plurals name="plural_remaining">
    <item quantity="one">%d Day Remaining</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d Days Remaining</item>
</plurals>

<plurals name="plural_ago">
    <item quantity="one">%d Day Ago</item>
    <item quantity="other">%d Days Ago</item>
</plurals>
```

How can I achieve the aforementioned solution without having to split them based on -ve and +ve number in android?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the absolute value of the quantity into the getQuantityString like this (in Kotlin) or Math.abs (in Java) :

```
getQuantityString(
   R.plurals.a_plural,
   quantityValue.absoluteValue,
   quantityValue
)
```

Its will handle : -1, 0, 1 and the others values